# how to show compact notification if it is available on the user device?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to show a compact notification like so (the one that expand and collapse):

```
mIcon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
             .setContentTitle(mContentTitle)
             .setContentText(mContentText)
             .setSmallIcon(mIcon)
             .setLargeIcon(mIcon2)
             .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle()
                 .bigText(mContentText))
             .build();
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Call requires API level 16 (current min is 11): android.app.Notification.Builder#setStyle
The method setLargeIcon(Bitmap) in the type Notification.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

First how to do a condition that check if setStyle is available on current device and if not show normal notification?

Second how to initialize the mIcon2 to have the same icon as mIcon only bigger since it doesn't take int?

3rd after the build how to actually trigger the notification to show up? is it the same as the old one like so

```
// show the notification
mNotificationManager.notify(1, noti);
```

4th What is the maximum count of characters for bigText?

Comment: Since your min API is 11 you should use `NotificationCompat` instead of `Notification`.

Comment: And NotificationCompat is found in the support library

Comment: ok I am currently trying it

Comment: yes. Use the NotificationCompat from the support library, you can just go and do anything and the library automatically handles versions for you

Comment: if so why didn't you give the solution as an Answer, i can't seem to find it

Comment: just did. Enjoy and happy coding!

Comment: ok i removed the correct answer check so that it wont lock, when i have the time to implement this, if it works as it should be I will be happy to give you the correct answer check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, it really depends on the specific details you want to use, but here an examples from the app I work at.

Note that I only try to load the image if it will be used, or else I'm wasting memory and download time.

That example shows a BigPicture style, but you can get from the docs the Inbox or BigText styles too.

```
// here is the base of a notification
NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
b.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_icon);
b.setContentTitle(title);
b.setContentText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
b.setTicker(title);
b.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

// notification shade open icon
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && url != null)
  try {
     b.setLargeIcon(Picasso.with(context).load(url)
           .resizeDimen(android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width,
              android.R.dimen.notification_large_icon_width).centerCrop().get());
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(this, "Failed to setLargeIcon", e);
     }

NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
s.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(msg));

// expanded notification icon
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
   if (expandedIconUrl != null) {
      try {
          s.bigLargeIcon(Picasso.with(context).load(expandedIconUrl).get());
        } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(this, "Failed to bigLargeIcon", e);
        }
   } else if (expandedIconResId > 0) {
        s.bigLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), expandedIconResId));
 }

 // background photo
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
   try {
       s.bigPicture(Picasso.with(context).load(bigImageUrl).get());
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(this, "Failed to bigPicture", e);
     }
  b.setStyle(s);
  b.setContentIntent( /* add here your pending intent */ );

  // here you can add up to 3 buttons to your notification
  b.addAction(R.drawable.ic_notification_photo,
                 context.getString(R.string.notificationAction_viewPhoto),
                 /* and here the button onClick pending intent */);
  Notification n = b.build();
  // now just show it with Notify.
```

Comment: i m using your code and trying to show notification inside Battery action changed reciver i m getting error 01-08 17:54:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(25734): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) } in com.example.batterylevel.BatteryService$1@4235d588
01-08 17:54:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773)
01-08 17:54:49.497: E/AndroidRuntime(25734):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

Answer (score -1):

this is what i have done:

```
public void createNotification() {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            createNotificationAPI11();
        } else {
            createNotificationOtherAPI();
        }
}
 private void createNotificationOtherAPI() {
// normal old notification
...
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void createNotificationAPI11() {
 //   new compact notification
....
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but even thou this method works, using the NotificationCompat from the support library you avoid having to do the code 2 times. Once for the API > 11 and again for API < 11. I mean, the guys from Google already wrote this code and put in the library, just use it.

Comment: well write the correct answer so that i can mark it as the correct one