# Notification with BigPicture, Large and Small Icon

Tags: android, push-notification

I have a notification implementation in 2 ways: 
1.LargeIcon + Small Icon (Title + Message)
2. LargeIcon + SmallIcon +Big Pictuire.(Title+ Message+ Mesage2(PicURL) )

First one is working okay,with Large Icon and Small Icon showed on bottom right corner.

For the Second implementation. I can See Big Picture + Small Icon.
But I see Large Icon only when I Expand Big Picture on notification.
How Can I show LargeIcon + Small Icon with Big picture on notification?

Here is the code:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String msg, String msg1) {
    Log.i("msg1", "" + msg1);
    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle s = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); //Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setDefaults(
                    Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                            | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    if(msg1 == null)
    {
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon);
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
        mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg));
    }
    else
    {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119374/how-to-show-compact-notification-if-it-is-available-on-the-user-device
            try {
                Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon);

                s.bigLargeIcon(largeIcon);
                s.bigPicture(Picasso.with(context).load(msg1).get());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mBuilder.setStyle(s);

        }
    }


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bgColor));
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    }


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    int notifID =(int)System.currentTimeMillis();
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first `else` condition you are not applying `mBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);` while you are applying `s.bigLargeIcon(largeIcon);` to your `NotificationBuilder style` not to notification builder.

so just add `mBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);` in your below code :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon);

        mBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bgColor));
    } else {
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    }
```